# How do I have the same video on iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, video

I have an app that was developed for iOS and Android (both are native). Both apps use the same api to download content such as images, documents, and videos. The video format is in mp4. Of course the videos play fine in iOS but some Android tablets have issues playing the videos reliably. Sometimes they play, sometimes (and usually) they don't.

Obviously this is a codec issue. I've suggested we have the user upload two videos, one for android and one for ios, but it doesn't seem to be an option at this point.

Is there a bitrate/fps setting that can be used to make video across both platforms more reliable?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What exactly are you trying to use to play the videos on Android devices?

Comment: I'm just using the video player a user has installed. I starting the intent and android either uses the default player or the user chooses the player. It's not being played within my application. The application only downloads the video to the device.

Comment: In that case you have no control over the way things will work as different 3rd party media player apps will have different default settings and different capabilities. You'd need to write your own video player to control things properly.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I had originally suggested two videos be upload based on platform but the client didn't want to maintain "double assets" or for changes to be made in the API. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Android should handle mp4 without a problem although it might depend on the encoding of the AV streams. The following is a link to media formats supported by Android natively http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html. If you can find something compatible across both platforms then you'd only need one video. In saying that though, if the user has a bad 3rd party video player installed you'd still have problems unless you write your own (tricky but not too hard to do).

Comment: We've had them try multiple players and the result is always the same. I think it is the encoding/codec of the video. Thanks for the info. I'll compare this with iOS "rules" and see if there is a middle ground.